# AWS IAM User Build

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Every time I create a user in IAM without admin access, they cannot enable MFA. I have looked at the policies and I cannot find a policy to assign to said user.

The error:

You need permissions
You do not have the permission required to perform this operation. Ask your administrator to add permissions.
User: arn:aws:iam::***:user/** is not authorized to perform: iam:ListVirtualMFADevices on resource: arn:aws:iam:****:mfa/ because no identity-based policy allows the iam:ListVirtualMFADevices action

I looked online and found a link containing a script that creates a policy for users to enable their own MFA. I ran the script and I cannot locate the policy: https://asecure.cloud/a/iam_iam_3/

If I create the user with full admin access in IAM, they can add MFA without any issues.

Comment: See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_iam_mfa-selfmanage.html.

Comment: Thank you. I ran that command in AWS CLI and I still can't allow users to add their own MFA

Comment: Have you checked in the AWS Console to see if your script *did* anything?

Comment: I ended up resolving this by copying a .json script to policies and editing the script slightly. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Setting up MFA requires making API calls.  Like most API actions in AWS, you cannot invoke the MFA API without permission to do so.  Your admins have such permission, but you give no indication that you gave your other Users that permission.

Amazon's documentation suggests the following permission policy to allow a User to configure and manage its own MFA:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowListActions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:ListUsers",
                "iam:ListVirtualMFADevices"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowUserToCreateVirtualMFADevice",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:CreateVirtualMFADevice"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:mfa/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowUserToManageTheirOwnMFA",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:EnableMFADevice",
                "iam:GetMFADevice",
                "iam:ListMFADevices",
                "iam:ResyncMFADevice"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::*:user/${aws:username}"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowUserToDeactivateTheirOwnMFAOnlyWhenUsingMFA",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iam:DeactivateMFADevice"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::*:user/${aws:username}"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "true"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "BlockMostAccessUnlessSignedInWithMFA",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "NotAction": [
                "iam:CreateVirtualMFADevice",
                "iam:EnableMFADevice",
                "iam:ListMFADevices",
                "iam:ListUsers",
                "iam:ListVirtualMFADevices",
                "iam:ResyncMFADevice"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "BoolIfExists": {
                    "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "false"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I suggest reviewing that permission policy to see if it is appropriate for you.  In particular, consider whether you want to allow your Users to disable MFA once it's activated.  Test your permission policy to ensure that it does what you want.  Once you've settled on an appropriate permission policy, create a Managed Policy and attach it to all of your Users (or attach it to a Group containing all of your Users).